# file_field in rails for image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-upload

I am having form for the user profile. In which there is a image field( I am using paperclip for image upload). I'm having an issue , when the user upload an image and again trying to upload and cancels the upload, the first image is not persisted. Is there any way to have the previously selected image?

Comment: If you want to save old images, you'll need to allow for multiple images to be associated with each User record. See the blog post [here](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/) for an idea how to do this.

Comment: I don't need to store multiple image, If the user drops an image and before submitting that, he  clicks the image field again and this time cancels the upload means the file tag removes the previously uploaded image

Comment: Yes, precisely. The fields that store information about the old image are deleted when the new attachment is selected. Without modifying Paperclip, I don't know any other way to solve your problem. But if you store multiple images, then you can revert to the most-recently uploaded image.

Comment: Saving the image value on clicking the image field. Will that work here

Comment: I suppose you can give it a try.

Comment: This is a default behaviour of dropify plugin too